# ReferencePath with the new .NET SDK?

Tags: csproj, dotnet-sdk

I am trying to specify a custom `ReferencePath` in my .csproj file, that uses the new format.

Here's how it looks like:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <ReferencePath>C:\...\binaries</ReferencePath>
</PropertyGroup>
```

With the following reference:

```
<Reference Include="MyDll">
  <Private>false</Private>
  <SpecificVersion>false</SpecificVersion>
</Reference>
```

`C:\...\binaries` contains MyDll.dll

However, during build I still get

> warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate
>   the assembly "MyDll". Check to make sure the
>   assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code,
>   you may get compilation errors.

I am trying to switch to `ReferencePath` from `HintPath`s, as they've become cumbersome to maintain.

Comment: It seems to me that the ReferencePath element is not supported anymore. Have you found any solution?

Comment: @Honzajscz not yet, still using `HintPath`s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the new SDK csproj you can use the **AssemblySearchPaths** variable instead of the **ReferencePath** variable to influence assembly probing

```
<AssemblySearchPaths>
  $(YOUR_SEMICOLON_SEPARATED_DIR_PATHS);$(AssemblySearchPaths);
</AssemblySearchPaths>
```

However, be careful with the old .NET Framework projects where this trick does not work.

Answer (score 0):

ReferencePath can be added manually to new csproj:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <AssemblySearchPaths>
       $(AssemblySearchPaths);
       $(ReferencePath);
    </AssemblySearchPaths>
</PropertyGroup>
```